# What is the best way to check WordPress Gutenberg blocks for a required field and show a notice when empty?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I know that the documentation for this is sparse, and the required field validation in Gutenberg is not what we're accustomed to in the classic editor.

However, Gutenberg does provide ways to lock and unlock saving a post (which disable or enables the Publish/Update button) and show or remove notices.

And I can loop through the blocks on the page to see if any are empty.

(There's also a separate discussion around what constitutes an "empty" block in Gutenberg, so for our purposes in this example, we're talking about a paragraph block with no content: either `'<p></p>'` or `''` depending on which attribute is used.)

What I'm having trouble with is finding a reasonable way to evaluate the blocks on the page without firing constantly. Ideally, we'd either check when the save/update button is clicked and before the post saves, or even when we leave (un-select) a block with a required field. But my limited understanding is that we don't want to use jQuery, javascript, or the DOM for changes, such as save/update button clicks/changes or input field onChange/onBlur.

Maybe that's where I'm wrong?

An example is below, which "works" insofar as it fires over and over and successfully evaluates empty paragraph blocks, but the section with the save locking and notices results in "maximum call stack size exceeded" errors. Using "subscribe" fires A LOT.

In a real-world scenario, this would more likely be a custom block or an ACF block, with more limited usage and maybe even just a single occurrence of this field on a given post, instead of this example where you might have 12 paragraphs.

Does anyone have any good advice on how to reasonably do this in a cleaner and more measured way?

```
const { subscribe } = wp.data;

let unsubscribe = subscribe( () => {

    let emptyBlocks = [];
    let emptyLock = false;

    let ourBlocks = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks();   

    let isEditedPostDirty = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).isEditedPostDirty();
    let isSavingPost = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).isSavingPost();
    let isAutosavingPost = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).isAutosavingPost();
    let isTyping = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).isTyping();
    let hasSelected = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).hasSelectedBlock();

    let emptyNotice = wp.data.select( 'core/notices' ).getNotices( 'emptyBlocksNotice' );

    if ( isEditedPostDirty && !isSavingPost && !isAutosavingPost && !isTyping && !hasSelected ) {

        Object.keys( ourBlocks ).forEach( function (item) {
            if ( ourBlocks[item].name == 'core/paragraph' && ourBlocks[item].attributes.content == '' ) {
                if ( emptyBlocks.indexOf( ourBlocks[item].clientId === -1 ) ) {
                    emptyBlocks.push( ourBlocks[item].clientId );
                }
                emptyLock = true;
            }
        });

        if ( emptyLock ) {
            wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).lockPostSaving( 'emptyBlocksLock' );

            if ( emptyNotice.length < 1 ) {
                wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createErrorNotice( 'You have empty paragraph blocks.', { id: 'emptyBlocksNotice', isDismissible: false } ) ;
            }
        } else if ( ! emptyLock ) {
            wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).unlockPostSaving( 'emptyBlocksLock' );

            if ( emptyNotice.length > 0 ) {
                wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).removeNotice( 'emptyBlocksNotice' );
            }
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: I found this guide helpful: https://rsvpmaker.com/blog/2019/03/07/my-gutenberg-breakthrough-adding-a-custom-notification/